# Javascript ReferenceError. Can't find variable:.... (in Python)

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt

I am trying to make work the example provided [here](https://github.com/vokimon/python-qgmap)

You can find the `.js` file and the **init**.py file in the qgmap directory.

However it launches, I got the message given in the title. It seems that the python code cannot see the variables given in the js file. I have installed json and I also use PyQt4 and Python3 like the author.

I have the following environment:

> '3.4.5 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 14:53:07) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]' on Windows 10

Could you please help what could be the trick I'm missing?

Sorry, if my question is too dumb, I have never used any link with JS before.

**EDIT:**

The main example code:

```
from qgmap import *

if __name__ == '__main__' :

def goCoords() :
    def resetError() :
        coordsEdit.setStyleSheet('')
    try : latitude, longitude = coordsEdit.text().split(",")
    except ValueError :
        coordsEdit.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, resetError)
    else :
        gmap.centerAt(latitude, longitude)
        gmap.moveMarker("MyDragableMark", latitude, longitude)

def goAddress() :
    def resetError() :
        addressEdit.setStyleSheet('')
    coords = gmap.centerAtAddress(addressEdit.text())
    if coords is None :
        addressEdit.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, resetError)
        return
    gmap.moveMarker("MyDragableMark", *coords)
    coordsEdit.setText("{}, {}".format(*coords))

def onMarkerMoved(key, latitude, longitude) :
    print("Moved!!", key, latitude, longitude)
    coordsEdit.setText("{}, {}".format(latitude, longitude))
def onMarkerRClick(key) :
    print("RClick on ", key)
    gmap.setMarkerOptions(key, draggable=False)
def onMarkerLClick(key) :
    print("LClick on ", key)
def onMarkerDClick(key) :
    print("DClick on ", key)
    gmap.setMarkerOptions(key, draggable=True)

def onMapMoved(latitude, longitude) :
    print("Moved to ", latitude, longitude)
def onMapRClick(latitude, longitude) :
    print("RClick on ", latitude, longitude)
def onMapLClick(latitude, longitude) :
    print("LClick on ", latitude, longitude)
def onMapDClick(latitude, longitude) :
    print("DClick on ", latitude, longitude)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = QtGui.QDialog()
h = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
l = QtGui.QFormLayout()
h.addLayout(l)

addressEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
l.addRow('Address:', addressEdit)
addressEdit.editingFinished.connect(goAddress)
coordsEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
l.addRow('Coords:', coordsEdit)
coordsEdit.editingFinished.connect(goCoords)
gmap = QGoogleMap(w)
gmap.mapMoved.connect(onMapMoved)
gmap.markerMoved.connect(onMarkerMoved)
gmap.mapClicked.connect(onMapLClick)
gmap.mapDoubleClicked.connect(onMapDClick)
gmap.mapRightClicked.connect(onMapRClick)
gmap.markerClicked.connect(onMarkerLClick)
gmap.markerDoubleClicked.connect(onMarkerDClick)
gmap.markerRightClicked.connect(onMarkerRClick)
h.addWidget(gmap)
gmap.setSizePolicy(
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
w.show()

gmap.waitUntilReady()

gmap.centerAt(41.35,2.05)
gmap.setZoom(13)
coords = gmap.centerAtAddress("Pau Casals 3, Santa Coloma de Cervelló")
# Many icons at: https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/
gmap.addMarker("MyDragableMark", *coords, **dict(
    icon="http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png",
    draggable=True,
    title = "Move me!"
    ))

# Some Static points
for place in [
    "Pau Casals 13, Santa Coloma de Cervelló",
    "Ferrer 20, Santa Coloma de Cervelló",
    ]:
    gmap.addMarkerAtAddress(place,
        icon="http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png",
        )

gmap.setZoom(17)



app.exec_()
```

The javascript code:

```
// main var
var map;
var markers=[];

// main init function
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
    map = new google.maps.Map(div, myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
        center = gmap_getCenter();
        qtWidget.mapMoved(center.lat(), center.lng());
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(ev) {
        qtWidget.mapClicked(ev.latLng.lat(), ev.latLng.lng());
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(ev) {
        qtWidget.mapRightClicked(ev.latLng.lat(), ev.latLng.lng());
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(ev) {
        qtWidget.mapDoubleClicked(ev.latLng.lat(), ev.latLng.lng());
    });
}

// custom functions
function gmap_setCenter(lat, lng)
{
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
}

function gmap_getCenter()
{
    return map.getCenter();
}

function gmap_setZoom(zoom)
{
    map.setZoom(zoom);
}

function gmap_addMarker(key, latitude, longitude, parameters)
{

    if (key in markers) {
        gmap_deleteMarker(key);
    }

    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    parameters['map'] = map
    parameters['position'] = coords;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(parameters);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        qtWidget.markerMoved(key, marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng())
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        qtWidget.markerClicked(key, marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng())
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {
        qtWidget.markerDoubleClicked(key, marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng())
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() {
        qtWidget.markerRightClicked(key, marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng())
    });

    markers[key] = marker;
    return key;
}

function gmap_moveMarker(key, latitude, longitude)
{
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    markers[key].setPosition(coords);
}

function gmap_deleteMarker(key)
{
    markers[key].setMap(null);
    delete markers[key]
}

function gmap_changeMarker(key, extras)
{
    if (!(key in markers)) {
        return
    }
    markers[key].setOptions(extras);
}
```

And the **init**.py

```
doTrace = False
usePySide = True
if usePySide :
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit, QtNetwork
else :
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit, QtNetwork
QtCore.Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal
QtCore.Slot = QtCore.pyqtSlot
QtCore.Property = QtCore.pyqtProperty

import json
import os
import decorator


@decorator.decorator
def trace(function, *args, **k) :
"""Decorates a function by tracing the begining and
end of the function execution, if doTrace global is True"""

if doTrace : print ("> "+function.__name__, args, k)
result = function(*args, **k)
if doTrace : print ("< "+function.__name__, args, k, "->", result)
return result

class _LoggedPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
@trace
def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, line, source):
    print ('JS: %s line %d: %s' % (source, line, msg))

class GeoCoder(QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager) :
class NotFoundError(Exception) : pass

@trace
def __init__(self, parent) :
    super(GeoCoder, self).__init__(parent)

@trace
def geocode(self, location) :
    url = QtCore.QUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml")
    url.addQueryItem("address", location)
    url.addQueryItem("sensor", "false")
    """
    url = QtCore.QUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo/")
    url.addQueryItem("q", location)
    url.addQueryItem("output", "csv")
    url.addQueryItem("sensor", "false")
    """
    request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(url)
    reply = self.get(request)
    while reply.isRunning() :
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    reply.deleteLater()
    self.deleteLater()
    return self._parseResult(reply)

@trace
def _parseResult(self, reply) :
    xml = reply.readAll()
    reader = QtCore.QXmlStreamReader(xml)
    while not reader.atEnd() :
        reader.readNext()
        if reader.name() != "geometry" : continue
        reader.readNextStartElement()
        if reader.name() != "location" : continue
        reader.readNextStartElement()
        if reader.name() != "lat" : continue
        latitude = float(reader.readElementText())
        reader.readNextStartElement()
        if reader.name() != "lng" : continue
        longitude = float(reader.readElementText())
        return latitude, longitude
    raise GeoCoder.NotFoundError


class QGoogleMap(QtWebKit.QWebView) :

@trace
def __init__(self, parent, debug=True) :
    super(QGoogleMap, self).__init__(parent)
    if debug :
        QtWebKit.QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(
            QtWebKit.QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
        self.setPage(_LoggedPage())

    self.initialized = False
    self.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)
    self.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject(
        "qtWidget", self)

    basePath=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    url = 'file://'+basePath+'/qgmap.html'
    self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))

@trace
def onLoadFinished(self, ok) :
    if self.initialized : return
    if not ok :
        print("Error initializing Google Maps")
    self.initialized = True
    self.centerAt(0,0)
    self.setZoom(1)

@trace
def waitUntilReady(self) :
    while not self.initialized :
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

@trace
def geocode(self, location) :
    return GeoCoder(self).geocode(location)

@trace
def runScript(self, script) :
    return self.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(script)

@trace
def centerAt(self, latitude, longitude) :
    self.runScript("gmap_setCenter({},{})".format(latitude, longitude))

@trace
def setZoom(self, zoom) :
    self.runScript("gmap_setZoom({})".format(zoom))

@trace
def center(self) :
    center = self.runScript("gmap_getCenter()")
    return center.lat, center.lng

@trace
def centerAtAddress(self, location) :
    try : latitude, longitude = self.geocode(location)
    except GeoCoder.NotFoundError : return None
    self.centerAt(latitude, longitude)
    return latitude, longitude

@trace
def addMarkerAtAddress(self, location, **extra) :
    if 'title' not in extra :
        extra['title'] = location
    try : latitude, longitude = self.geocode(location)
    except GeoCoder.NotFoundError : return None
    return self.addMarker(location, latitude, longitude, **extra)

@trace
def addMarker(self, key, latitude, longitude, **extra) :
    return self.runScript(
        "gmap_addMarker("
            "key={!r}, "
            "latitude={}, "
            "longitude={}, "
            "{}"
            "); "
            .format( key, latitude, longitude, json.dumps(extra)))

@trace
def moveMarker(self, key, latitude, longitude) :
    return self.runScript(
        "gmap_moveMarker({!r}, {}, {});".format(key,latitude,longitude))

@trace
def setMarkerOptions(self, keys, **extra) :
    return self.runScript(
        "gmap_changeMarker("
            "key={!r}, "
            "{}"
            "); "
            .format( keys, json.dumps(extra)))

@trace
def deleteMarker(self, key) :
    return self.runScript(
        "gmap_deleteMarker("
            "key={!r} "
            "); "
            .format( key))

mapMoved = QtCore.Signal(float, float)
mapClicked = QtCore.Signal(float, float)
mapRightClicked = QtCore.Signal(float, float)
mapDoubleClicked = QtCore.Signal(float, float)

markerMoved = QtCore.Signal(str, float, float)
markerClicked = QtCore.Signal(str)
markerDoubleClicked = QtCore.Signal(str)
markerRightClicked = QtCore.Signal(str)
```

And the error messages...

JS: undefined line 1: ReferenceError: Can't fin variable: gmap_setCenter
...

Comment: Please, post all relevant code, error messages here, we shouldn't have to go hunting for it to look at it

Comment: @PatrickEvans, you are right, please find the relevant codes in the updated question.